# Im looking for a book about parallel worlds

Tags: story-identification, magic, parallel-universe

So there is this book I read a while ago on Kindle unlimited and forgot about, and now cant find the name because KU doesn't store books that you have already read :(

It is about this guy who gets teleported to another world and loses an eye in the process, ends up in a prison in this other world, and this guy with an emerald for an eye uses some healing power to heal the dudes eye but turns it into a diamond/crystal? they escape the prison and join up with a resistance or something.  Basically certain people have gemstones for eyes that relate to specific powers, like healing is emerald, violet is emotion, idk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's [Gemworld](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00MJNSGW0).

I remember it matching all the plot points you call out (transported to alternate world, prison, escape, join the resistance, gemstone eyes).  I also seem to recall it had strong Christian Fantasy leanings.

Also, check [this](http://www.amazon.com/forum/kindle?_encoding=UTF8&cdForum=Fx1D7SY3BVSESG&cdThread=Tx1T7YXEK4O5MYS) out for KU history.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks, I wanted to see if a second book in the series had come out yet, but it looks like it hasn't.  Thanks again!